# Elements inside div with z-index:-1 does not show up even though z-index is more than -1

Tags: html, css, html-table

As a developer trainee, my company ask me to do a Gantt Chart in purely HTML and CSS, below first picture can be used for reference:

Those grey coloured boxes contains Milestones and description boxes.Those grey boxes does not placed in the same container the timetable used

[image: Here's the Gantt Chart]

Since this Gantt Chart is a timetable, so I use table to put those timetable contents
[image: The blue coloured circle and the text next to it are timetable contents]

The blue coloured circle is and text next to it are timetable contents

Here's the issue, the timetable with the black border outside it (`#chart_box`) contains `z-index:-1`, but contents from those `<td>` with class `cb_contents_tb` does not shows up on these grey boxes, even though I used `z-index:5`

Here's the full code

```css
#header {
    background-color:lightblue;
    width:25%;
    margin-top:3%;
    height:10%;
    line-height: 10%;
    position: absolute;
}

#chart_box {
    border: solid;
    z-index:-1;
    margin-left:20%;
    margin-top:5%;
    height:85%;
    width: 75%;
    position: absolute;
}

#tr_header {
    border:solid;
}

th {
    background-color:lightgray;
    border-left-color:white;
    padding:15px;
    padding-left:60px;
    padding-right:60px;
}

td.empty_row {
    border-left-style:dotted;
    border-left-color:lightgray;
    height:20px;
    padding:15px;
    padding-left:60px;
    padding-right:60px;
}

td.empty_row_last {
    border-left-style:dotted;
    border-right-style:solid;
    border-left-color:lightgray;
    border-right-color:lightgray;
    height:20px;
    padding:15px;
    padding-left:60px;
    padding-right:60px;
}

td.empty_row_first {
    border-left-style:solid;
    border-left-color:lightgray;
    height:20px;
    padding:15px;
    padding-left:60px;
    padding-right:60px;
}


td.cb_contents_tb {
    display:table-cell;
    z-index:5;
    position: absolute;
    padding-left:60px;
    padding-right:60px;
    height:80px;
}

td.spanned {
    text-align:center;
}

.cb_contents {
    display:inline-block;
    z-index:1;
}

.content_box {
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:rgb(216, 214, 214);
    overflow:visible;
    background-color:rgb(216, 214, 214);
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    z-index:1;
}

.content_box_title {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
}

.blue-circle {
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:white;
    background-color:aqua;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Gantt Chart (Week)</title>

        <!-- stylesheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    </head>

    <body style="margin-left:0px;">
            <div id="header">
                <h2 style="text-align:center;line-height:1;">Gantt Chart (Week)</h2>
            </div>


        
        <div style="position:absolute;z-index:1;margin:14% 1%;width:87%;margin-left:6%;">
            <!-- Planning Task -->
            <div class="content_box">
                <h4 class="content_box_title">Planning Task</h4>
            </div>

            <!-- Introduction Task -->
            <div class="content_box">
                <h4 class="content_box_title">Introduction Task</h4>
            </div>

            <!-- Team Selection -->
            <div class="content_box">
                <h4 class="content_box_title">Team Selection</h4>
            </div>

            <!-- Execution Task -->
            <div class="content_box">
                <h4 class="content_box_title">Execution Task</h4>
            </div>


            
        </div>

        <!-- Chart Tables -->
        <div id="chart_box">

            <table style="margin:5% 9%;z-index:2;">
                <tr id="tr_header">
                    <th>Mon</th>
                    <th>Tue</th>
                    <th>Wed</th>
                    <th>Thu</th>
                    <th>Fri</th>
                    <th>Sat</th>
                </tr>

                <!-- Empty Row -->
                <tr>
                    <td class="empty_row_first"></td>
                    <td class="empty_row"></td>
                    <td class="empty_row"></td>
                    <td class="empty_row"></td>
                    <td class="empty_row"></td>
                    <td class="empty_row_last"></td>
                </tr>
    
                <tr>
                    <td class="cb_contents_tb" colspan="2">
                        <div class="blue-circle" style="z-index:5;position:absolute;"></div>
                        <span style="z-index:5;position:absolute;">Milestone 1 (Data)</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
    
            </table>
    

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is, make contents to display in front of grey boxes (`.content_box`)

Comment: don't put separate codes, try to create a complete one that we can run and test

Comment: Hey @TemaniAfif I have edited and added a code snippet to the original post

Comment: remove z-index:-1; from chart box and increase the z-index of header

Answer (score 0):

You should consider that every element containing other elements can function as a reference for z-indexing. See example below. So make sure the structure of your code makes it posible.

Since your #chart_box has z-index:-1 , the table will be below the content_box titles.
**Solution: move the table outside the #chart_box and position the table absolutely.**

```css
#one{
position:relative;
z-index:1;

  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  background-color:#00c;
}

#four{
 position:absolute;
 z-index:4;
  left:20px;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  background-color:#fc0;
 }
 
 #two{
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
  top:-20px;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  background-color:#c00;
 }
```

```html
<div id="one">
1
  <div id="four">4</div>
 </div>
 
 <div id="two">
 2
 </div>
```